# Non-negatively curved manifolds and the volume of balls

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Whether a complete non-compact non-flat Riemannian $n$-manifold $M$ with non-negative sectional curvature has Euclidean volume growth?

That is, whether there is a constant $C>0$ such that  $\mathrm{Vol}(B_x(r))\geq Cr^n$ for all $r>0$ and $x\in M$? Here  $\mathrm{Vol}(B_x(r))$ is  the volume of the  $r$-ball in $M$.

Since  manifolds with non-negative Ricci curvature and Euclidean volume growth are studied a lot, I am curious about the non-negative sectional curvature case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is certainly not true that every complete nonflat open manifold of nonnegative curvature has Euclidean volume growth. Counterexamples are trivial to construct. Say, a capped cylinder. More generally any nonnegatively curved manifold $M^n$ with nontrivial soul has slower than Euclidean volume growth. Because its asymptotic cone at infinity has dimension strictly smaller than $n$ if the soul is not a point while manifolds with Euclidean volume growth have asymptotic cones of dimension $n$.

This also implies that any nonnegatively curved manifold with Euclidean volume growth is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb  R^n$.

Comment: Futhermore,  does it  imply that the metric is isometric to the Euclidean metric up to scaling?  Whether it also holds for complete non-compact Alexandroff spaces (with n-dimensional Hausdorff  dimension or n-dimensional topological dimension) with curvature bounded below by 0?

Comment: @JialongDeng I don't understand the question. Does what imply that the metric is Euclidean? and what statement about Alexandrov spaces are you asking?

Comment: The question askes for the statement in the last part of your answer.

Comment: if you are asking whether a nonnegatively curved manifold with Euclidean volume growth (meaning $vol B_r(p)\ge cr^n$) must be isometric to $\mathbb R^n$ that is certainly false. if you are asking something else please clarify.

Comment: Yes, there is my question. And whether a complete non-compact Alexandroff spaces (with n-dimensional Hausdorff dimension or n-dimensional topological dimension) with curvature bounded below by 0 and Euclidean volume growth  is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R} ^n$?

Comment: certainly not to both. for the first question you can take a cone over a small circle and smooth out the tip to have nonnegative curvature. this could be realized by a surface of revolution in $\mathbb R^3$ for the second. nonnegatively curved Alexandrov spaces with Euclidean volume growth don't need to be smooth or even topological manifolds. e.g. a metric cone over any $(n-1)$ -dimensional Alexandrov space of curvature $\ge 1$ is Alexandrov of curvature $\ge 0$ and has Euclidean volume growth.